# calculate distance from 2 points lat and lon in ms sql select command

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have table with places and each have lat and lon points
I have lat lon point and wanted distance in KM,
I need to find matching rows in db for this distance with select command

is there any way to do it, witout selecting all rows and run function for each point to calcultae the distance?

thanks

Comment: You should be able to reduce the available set of lat/lon points based on your origin and distance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all!
here is the answer:

```
    String SelectString = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,(((acos(sin((";
    SelectString += userLat;
    SelectString += "*pi()/180)) * sin((latPoint*pi()/180))+cos((";
    SelectString += userLat;
    SelectString += "*pi()/180)) * cos((latPoint*pi()/180)) * cos(((";
    SelectString += userLon;
    SelectString += "- lonPoint)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515*1.609344) as distance FROM MYTABLE ) t WHERE distance <=";
    SelectString += userDistance;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what version of SQL Server you're using - 2008 has geo-query capability which might avoid the 'select all rows' concern you have. Otherwise, this blog post might help: http://johndyer.name/latitudelongitude-distance-calculation-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I like to use computed columns for this. Specifically, create a computed column of geography type that is your lat/lon. One you have that, you can use all of the spatial methods you want against that column.

Comment: true, i will do it only if i want to show this columns else id rather use the complicated select statment

Comment: The only reason it would matter if your table had more columns than you intend to display is if you're relying on "select *" somewhere. Which you shouldn't because that's a bad idea.